# How can I improve page load speed in Rails 2.3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using CANVAS LMS which is with rails 2.3.

In the production environment, it is loading fast because of caching. But in the development environment, I want to make page load approx same as the production environment.

I can not use caching in the devlopment because each time needs to do the same process like restart server etc.

Comment: Just want to improve page load nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Production env is fast precisely **because** it doesn't do any kind of reloading. So you have to choose what's more important to you: accurate live reloading of changes or page load speed. You can't have both.

Comment: Each click it's taking 20-30 second page loading time in dev env. SO I want to Improve page load time. Just need to improve page load.

Comment: @umishra: in this case, you need to find out what's taking so long and see if you can disable it without hurting development behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Sergio Tulentsev